# how can I convert a list containing apostrophe and numbers to numbers (e.g ['2,2.4,3'] to [2,2.4,3]) in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, numpy, scipy

how can I convert a list containing apostrophe and numbers to numbers (e.g `['2,2.4,3']` to `[2,2.4,3]`) in Python?

I've tried this:

```
z = [float(x) if type(x) is str else None for x in ['1 2 3 4']]
```

Comment: You need to split the list first

Comment: `z = [float(p) for s in ['2,2.4,3'] for p in s.split(',')]` or if the outer list is always a single element, `z = [float(p) for p in ['2,2.4,3'].split(',')]`

Comment: `list(map(float, ['2,2.4,3'][0].split(',')))`

Comment: That's not "a list containing apostrophe and numbers", that's a list containing a string.

Answer (score 1):

You can check first that digit is float or int then convert according to its type():

```
def flat(lst):
    result=[]
    for i in lst:
        if isinstance(i,str):
            for item in i.split(','):

                if '.' in item:
                    result.append(float(item))
                else:
                    result.append(int(item))
    return result

print(flat(['2,2.4,3']))
```

output:

```
[2, 2.4, 3]
```

if you want in all in float then:

```
def flat(lst):
    result=[]
    for i in lst:
        if isinstance(i,str):
            for item in i.split(','):
                result.append(float(item))
    return result

print(flat(['2,2.4,3']))
```

output:

```
[2.0, 2.4, 3.0]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
l = ['2,2.4,3']
list(map(float,l[0].split(',')))
#[2.0, 2.4, 3.0]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this generic solution:

```
import itertools

ll = ['2,2.4,3']

list(map(float, itertools.chain(*[str_.split(",") for str_ in ll])))
# [2.0, 2.4, 3.0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you tagged with `numpy` I'm assuming you are ok with `array`s as output. In this case the easiest is using `np.fromstring`:

```
x = ['2,2.4,3']
np.fromstring(x[0], sep=',')
# array([ 2. ,  2.4,  3. ])

x = ['1 2 3 4']
np.fromstring(x[0], sep=' ')
# array([ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.])

np.fromstring(x[0], sep=' ', dtype=int)
# array([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

Apart from that I do recommend you make sure you read and understand @Stefan Pochmann's comment.

Answer (score 0):

If your list always has one string, you could try this:

```
>>> lst = ['2,2.4,3']
>>> result = [float(x) for x in lst[0].split(',')]
>>> print(result)
[2.0, 2.4, 3.0]
```

Or if you have multiple strings:

```
>>> lst = ['2,2.4,3', '2,3.4,5.3']
>>> result = [[float(x) for x in y.split(',')] for y in lst]
>>> print(result)
[[2.0, 2.4, 3.0], [2.0, 3.4, 5.3]]
```

If you want to flatten the final list:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> print(list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(result)))
[2.0, 2.4, 3.0, 2.0, 3.4, 5.3]
```

Answer (score 0):

### Try with This:-

```
a = ['2,2.4,3']
for i in a:
    print list(eval(i))
```